# executing portlet event phase without render phase

Tags: events, liferay, portlet

I need to cancel renderProcessing (doView method) from executing after processing Action or Event phase (As i don't want the whole page or any portlets to be refreshed). Something like ajax resource acquiring which is not leading to refresh all portlets (I mean serveResource method). Can we use "destroy()" method at the end of ProcessAction or ProcessEvent to prevent renderPhase from executing. I'm using MVCPortlet framework and events ipc extensively in my portlets. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, you can't. You can only override destroy method, this method should be called by container. Why  you do not use ajax and serveResource?

Comment: because my portlets receive and send events to other portlets to run a multistage process and i don't want to let them to refresh the page in each event processing. Maybe I should override doView process to ignore some specific renderRequset base on some conditions or parameters(but how?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Georgy Gobozov stated in the comment: The answer to your question is "No".

If you are using the standard portlet request handling and rely on event handling, you're bound to a full page reload. There's nothing that keeps you from implementing custom event handling (e.g. with JS on the browser, through your business layer etc.) but unfortunately you'll have to do exactly this.

When you start the original request, e.g. through an action handler, the page has already started to reload (from the browser perspective). Any attempt to cancel the processing server side will result in the stream to break and the browser signalling an error on the page (e.g. "can't load": The result must come with an HTTP status - and it will most likely be an error code (e.g. 50x), or it must contain the whole page's HTML.